# How to get the text field value and push that value to an arrayList

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to get the text field value and push that value to an arrayList in react js?

I want to get the value from the text box and push it to Modules array so that i can render the values by iterating it.

I tried to use ref but getting error.

Can you help me?

```
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
          this.state={
            module:'',
            Modules: []
          }
        }

        change (event){
            this.setState({
              [event.target.name]:event.target.value
            });
          };

        createModule (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("submitted",this.state.module);
          this.setState(previousState => ({
              ...state,
              thisModules: [...previousState.Modules, 'new value']
          }));
        };

      render(){
        return(

            <form className="form-inline">
                  <div className="form-group">
                            Module Name:
                            <input type="text" id="module" 
                                name="module" 
                                  placeholder="module"  
                                    className="form-control" 
                                      ref="Module"
                                        value ={this.state.module}
                                          onChange={event => this.change(event)}/>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event) => this.createModule(event)}>Add Module</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What's the code you have so far looking like? Could you please post it?

Comment: I want to get the text field value and push the value to an ArrayList, so that i can render those values.

Answer (score 0):

`mylist.push(document.getElementById('textbox_id').value)`

with mylist as your list and textbox_id as the id of the textbox should work.

Consider this is plain javascript as I don't really see any difference with react.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem from running your code was that in `createModule` you weren't putting `this` in front of `state`. If you'd given details of the error this would have helped.

There were a few other typos, and a work solution is below.

```js
class ModuleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      module:'',
      Modules: []
    }
  }

  change (event){
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }

  createModule (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted",this.state.module);
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...this.state,
      Modules: [...previousState.Modules, this.state.module]
    }));
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <form className="form-inline">
        <div className="form-group">
          Module Name:
            <input type="text" id="module" 
              name="module" 
              placeholder="module"  
              className="form-control" 
              ref="Module"
              value={this.state.module}
              onChange={event => this.change(event)}/>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event) => this.createModule(event)}>Add Module</button>
          </div>
        
          <ul>
          {
            this.state.Modules.map(
              (m) => <li>{m}</li>
            )
          }
          </ul>
        </form>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ModuleList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<p>My App:</p>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Thanks Piran, thanks a lot. i have done some mistakes. Thanks for Guiding.One more thing, how can i pass the modules array from this component to other and how can i access the array in that component.

Comment: @mohan That's really a very different question, and should be asked in a separate SO Question. It depends if you want to pass the modules to an inner component, a parent component, or to any other component. If the answer is the latter, then you should start thinking about using redux or similar libraries.